# image button with html5

Tags: image, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make an image button. I'm using/learning html5 and jquery mobile. this is my sample code:

```
<img src="img/beer.png" alt="beer" />
<input type="image" src="img/beer.png" />
```

the image is displayed, but the input type doesn't show the image. what do i do wrong ?

Comment: your code is working, when i don't use jquery libraries. Has anyone a idea how i can use the button element with an image and using jquery mobile libraries like this
http://jsfiddle.net/cyB7B/3/

Answer (score 24):

`<input type="image" src="img/beer.png" />` is meant to collect coordinates. If you want to use it as a submit-button, you'll have to add an `onsubmit`-event, e.g.

```
<input type="image" src="img/beer.png" onsubmit="submit();" />
```

But you should rather use the `<button>`-element, which is way more flexible. It can contain text, images or both:

```
<button type="submit" name="beer" value="beer_btn_was_clicked">
  Here's some optional text,
  <p>which you can even put in a paragraph!</p>

  And you don't even need JavaScript!

  <img src="img/beer.png" />
</button>
```

---

## Edit (2016-02-12)

As of today*, the above example is not considered 100% valid because **`<p>`-elements are not allowed within a `<button>`-element anymore**.

According to the [MDN HTML element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) the only permitted content category within a `<button>`-element is the so called *[Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)*:

> Phrasing content defines the text and the mark-up it contains. Runs of phrasing content make up paragraphs.
>
> Elements belonging to this category are `<abbr>`, `<audio>`, `<b>`, `<bdo>`, `<br>`, `<button>`, `<canvas>`, `<cite>`, `<code>`, `<command>`, `<datalist>`, `<dfn>`, `<em>`, `<embed>`, `<i>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<kbd>`, `<keygen>`, `<label>`, `<mark>`, `<math>`, `<meter>`, `<noscript>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<q>`, `<ruby>`, `<samp>`, `<script>`, `<select>`, `<small>`, `<span>`, `<strong>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<svg>`, `<textarea>`, `<time>`, `<var>`, `<video>`, `<wbr>` and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).
>
> A few other elements belong to this category, but only if a specific condition is fulfilled:
>
> - `<a>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<area>`, if it is a descendant of a  element
> - `<del>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<ins>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<link>`, if the itemprop attribute is present
> - `<map>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<meta>`, if the itemprop attribute is present

<sub>*today was that I read about it, not when the change was introduced</sub>

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the difference between the "legal" and "illegal" examples of `img` elements inside `button` elements in the w3c docs [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).  The only difference I see is that in the example cited as illegal, the content of the 'button` consists entirely of the `img`

Comment: @user1269964 It's not about the image itself, it's about the **[image map](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map)**. So it's not allowed to use the *usemap*-attribute for *img*-element within a button element. That's one of the few restrictions for content within a *button*-element (not sure if forms are valid content for *button*).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cyB7B/

This works for me...have you got any other code that could be interfering? CSS maybe?