# How can I make an Image clickable to a javascript script

Tags: javascript, html

So this is the code!

```
<a class="gray" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://forms.zohopublic.com/cpmovers/form/Locationupdates/formperma/0e5D2g0E23J372HC4Dek22J43');">Customer Form</a>
```

What I want to be done is so instead of the submit button. I want it to be the logo, so it can be clickable. I hope I explained myself well.  An image turned into a clickable that leads to this whole code.

Comment: Don't use inline events, attach an external event listener

Comment: Certainly don't use the `javascript:` protocol handler.

Comment: If all you want is an image to be the submit button on a form, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734365/451969). There's a simpler way to do it using `<input type='image' ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the image tag... but you need to set an onclick attribute for the image tag
example:

```
<img src='img/name.jpg' onclick='myFunction()'/>
```

and inside javascript you will have:

```
function myfunction(){
  document.getElementById('formId').submit();
 }
```

As i see that link re-directs you to a form, what you will need to do is to position the image where the submit button was and then add the script so when you click the image it will submit the form you have on your page

Comment: it not invalid, if you follow the link he posted it will show you a form, maybe i just need to be more clear but is not invalid code

Comment: `image` isn't a tag, I believe you are thinking of the *self closing* `<img />` tag

Comment: Correct @SterlingArcher except the `<img>` tag does not have or need a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob true, although I will argue that some frameworks (React for example) require self closing tags ending slash, but you're right. In regular JS, it's optional.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Despite what React or anyone else does, there is nothing in the HTML `<img>` tag specification saying anything about a closing slash. Never has been.

Comment: @Rob https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements a self closing tag is calleda void element, and it covers that in the Smart Tags section. "Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single "/" (U+002F) character. This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing."

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes but I said to look at the HTML spec for the `<img>` tag and you will find it is not specified. I didn't say to look at exceptions. However, if you read further and in other sections about void elements in HTML, you will find that that closing slash does nothing, has no meaning and is ignored which, therefore, makes it pointless and useless.

Comment: Using a `/` to end off a tag is one of the things I prefer to do. It doesn't affect how the code runs in any way, it just keeps things neater.

Comment: @Rob Why have a multi-comment digression on the fatuousness of a ridiculous ending slash? We fought the XHTML/HTML war a long time ago. It's useless but also ignored, who cares?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Because it's useless and ignored and takes up space, that's why. Do you often do things that are ridiculous, useless, ignored and only take up space?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'll add that my point was to help the questioner with his markup. What is your point in arguing with me about it?

Comment: @Rob - Get you off his case. And no, I'm not going to bite and get into some running argument.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Rather than teach proper markup, you find it more important to not teach and be silent. Understood.